How to prioritize split characters within ISplitCharacters in iText 7
Working with iText 7 splitcharacters, I want a string that has to be split to always split on hyphens or spaces if they exist regardless of the location of that character and if they don't exist split on any character. However, all of the splitcharacter implementations (Default, BreakAll, KeepAll) always seem to split on the last valid split character regardless of the characters that are present.
Is there a way to "prioritize" which characters are used to split a string?
Example:
If I have the string "a-1234567890" and it will split after 8 character I want it to split like this:
a-
12345678
90
But what I am getting is:
a-123456
7890

The sample string that you've provided doesn't contain a hyphen  (-) or a space  -- it contains an underscore (_) which some may also refer to as a dash.

Apologies for that, not having a hyphen was a typo in the example. It has been fixed now
